# no keyboard/touchpad access

Tags: windows

I have lost contact with the built in keyboard and touchpad.
If I shutdown the computer in sleepmode and start it again, the keyboard works, but not the touchpad.

The "PS/2-compatible mouse" = "touchpad" in the devicemanager have an exclamation symbol
and the reason "This device is not present, is not working properly, or does not have all its drivers installed. (Code 24)"

The support at SONY,  suggest a reinstallation of windows 7.
I have a lot at applications installed so I wont do this.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The touchpad may be internally connected to USB (even when displaying PS/2), so please check the power management settings for the USB controller in the device manager. You can find instrcutions here: http://www.ehow.com/how_6854952_disable-usb-power-management.html
Doublecheck you have the latest drivers for everything installed.

Some BIOSes do have options like "If external mouse handle touchpad as" and you may set the option accordingly not to use PS/2.

Just for testing you may insert a fresh hdd or use one on external SATA and freshly install windows 7 to see if the error is OS related anyway.

Comment: I heave unchecked the box "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power." for all USB devices. and restarted the PC. Nothing changed.

Comment: could you try the second windows installation approach? I would also try installing the touchpad drivers, as "PS/2 Mouse" suggests they are not yet installed. Also revert the USB power changes as they did not help but may make you battery live shorter

Comment: I do have a 2'd disk but the SONY-PC was preinstalled with windows 7 .

Comment: I do have a 2'd disc but the SONY-PC was preinstalled with windows 7. So I don't have any cd/dvd with windows 7. I have to Clone the 2 discs first, so this will take som time. (I have to bye a cabinett to the 2'd disc first) I have installed Linux Ubunto to the 2'd disc and then the keybord works, but not the touchpad. so the problem with keaboard i do thisk is software/driver problem. and the touchpad problem is probably hardware.